# TypeScript dynamic property filtering mobx observable list

Tags: javascript, typescript, mobx

I have a calendar application I am building in React using Typescript. I am currently trying to store all my calendar events in a single observable object and select an array of events based on date

My events object looks like this

```
events = {
    '17-08-2020': [Array of events],
    '18-08-2020': [{}, {}, {}]
}
```

The idea behind this structure is that the date key will always be unique so a I can easily just push events into an array that this key identifies.

The problem occurs with typescript restricting me. When I access the store in my component I get this error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`.

When I try and use a computed property to get the element in my store I get `getter must not have any formal parameters`

**Store**

```
@observable events = {}

@computed 
get filteredEvents(key) {
    return this.events[key]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tell typescript that keys can be any string and not only predefined strings that you have on your events object.

```
events: {[key: string]: CalendarEventType[]} = {
  '17-08-2020': [{}, {}, {}],
  '18-08-2020': [{}, {}, {}]
}
```

For computed values with parameters you can follow the docs: [Computeds with arguments](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html#computeds-with-arguments)